# How to update exisiting date field in django using existing days field?

Tags: python, django

I want to update existing date field in django using existing days field in the same table.

For example

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    notify_status = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    next_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    days = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I want to add `days` `to next_date` where `next_date` is less than todays date.

I have tried this:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import F

Sample.objects.filter(next_date__lt=today).update(next_date=F('next_date')+datetime.timedelta(days=F('days')))
```

But its not working.
Here is the output

```
Something went wrong in period_retrack.py: unsupported type for timedelta days component: F
```

Expected Output
I want next_date to be increased by the number of days in the same table for every row where next_date is less than current_date i.e, today's date

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please specify why it isn't working? What result do you expect and what result are you getting?

Comment: @DanielHolmes Hi, this is the ouput I am getting: Something went wrong in period_retrack.py: unsupported type for timedelta days component: F

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the `days` field value to an interval at the database level:

```
import datetime

from django.db.models import CharField, DurationField, F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Concat

Sample.objects.filter(next_date__lt=today).update(
    next_date=F("next_date")
    + Cast(
        Concat("days", Value(" days"), output_field=CharField()),
        output_field=DurationField(),
    )
)
```

Notice that I'm doing the cast in 2 steps:

1. Concatenate the value with the " days" suffix (e.g. "1 days")
2. Cast this string to a duration

This would work with Postgres, I'm not sure about other databases.